# When do I need to get a new shell for my snail?

Tags: health, snails

I understand that snail shells do not grow with the snail. I haven't tried anything yet because I don't want to hurt my snail, but how do I know when it needs a new shell?

Answer (score 4):

The shell of snails do infact grow along with the snail. The link below might help answer this question in more detail.

http://mentalfloss.com/article/48796/are-snails-born-shells

Comment: While your answer is correct, it's not really good form to use a link to another website as your answer. See: [Why are link-only answers bad?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/a/778/481)